# Using testacular is it possible to run Jasmine and Mocha through tests at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, mocha.js, karma-runner

Using testacular is it possible to run Jasmine and Mocha through tests at the same time using the same configuration file 'testacular.conf.js and running it in intellij?

OR can you only use one at a time? So only Jasmine OR Mocha?

Answer (score 0):

No worries. So far I found out it is impossible but that is ok. I am using chai to replace jasmine. However, now i have problems with angular-mocks.js being understood. New problem woo